# XMLHttpRequest cannot load json file. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

There are some threads with the similar question. Tried to read them. But dint get any satisfactory answer. 
I am trying to access this json file: http://www.fastel.se/emedius/products.json. I got the above error.

I understand that cross domain access is not allowed. I tried to use the jsonp.

Below is my code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.fastel.se/emedius/products.json",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: 'callback',
        success: function (data) {
            var content = "";
            for(property in data)
                for(product in data[property]) 
                    content += Object.keys(data[property][product])[0] + ", ";

            document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = content;
        },
    });
```

But I got this error: "**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :**".

It appears this error is because the server doesn''t support jsonp requests.

Is there any possible way I can access this json file without doing any modifications on the server side?

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any possible way I can access this json file without doing
>   any modifications on the server side?

No, there isn't. In order to be able to do cross domain AJAX requests the remote server must support [`JSONP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or [`CORS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

If you have no control over the remote server you could write a server side script on your domain that will act as a bridge and then send the AJAX request to your script.